# rule that evaluates mail upon arrival to a folder and moves it to another folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-filter

Want to create a rule that evaluates an email by subject upon arrival to a folder and moves it to another folder - is that possible within outlook 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Outlook 2010 supports rules just like the previous versions.  Microsoft has posted instructions [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-custom-actions-rules-HA010354989.aspx?CTT=3).